# Can not use functions of lmoments3 with Python 3.x

Tags: python

Installed with Navigator, package is there. But I can not use all functions from this package getting such as module 'lmoments3' has no attribute 'pelge' error.

help needed module installed, there is no error at other modules.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and check out [ask]. I'm not familiar with this library, but FWIW, you should probably make a [mre] including enough code to reproduce the issue and the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). Also mention what troubleshooting you've already done, like to start, have you checked the docs to make sure "pelge" exists and in the same place you expected?

Comment: Why were you expecting anything named `pelge` to exist?  I see nothing even similar to that in the documentation for this module.

Comment: Seen an example code and took it from there. Where can I find documentation for functions?

Comment: @FSinan.  if you go to the [pypi.org page](https://pypi.org/project/lmoments3/)  for the lmoments3 package, there are various related links.  Unfortunately the link to "read the docs" is broken, but under Project Details, the [Homepage](https://lmoments3.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)  link will get you to the correct page for documentation.